# Why print outside observe block is executed before print(count) inside observe block?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
func teacherExists(teacherName: String) -> Bool
    {
        var dataBaseRef2: DatabaseReference!
        dataBaseRef2 = Database.database().reference()
        let teachersTableRef = dataBaseRef2.child("teachers")
        self.teachersList.removeAll()
        teachersTableRef.observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

       // teachersTableRef.observe(.value)
        //{
          //  snapshot in
            let teachersNamesDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] ?? [:]
            for(key, _) in teachersNamesDictionary
            {
                if let teacherDict = teachersNamesDictionary[key] as? [String: Any]
                {
                    if let teacher = Teacher(dictionary: teacherDict)
                    {
                        //print(teacher.teacher_name)
                        self.teachersList.append(teacher.teacher_name)
                    }
                }
            }
            print(self.teachersList.count)
        })
        print("Outside \(self.teachersList)")
        return false
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [Firebase APIs are all asynchronous](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93).  It would be bad for your app if they blocked your code path, because that could cause your app to hang indefinitely.

`observeSingleEvent` returns *immediately*, and the passed observer gets invoked some time later, whenever the data is finally ready.  Execution continues on the next line, which prints to the console.

Comment: so how do I read all the data from firebase server and check for duplicate values?

Comment: or how can I suspend the execution of next statement until the data has been passed by firebase servers?

Comment: Generally speaking, you don't.  You deal with the asynchronous APIs by adapting your code to them.  If you want something to run after the observer runs, kick off that work inside the observer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use closure to callback after check for duplicate

```
func teacherExists(teacherName: String, completion: @escaping ((Bool) -> Void)) -> Void {
    var dataBaseRef2: DatabaseReference!
    dataBaseRef2 = Database.database().reference()
    let teachersTableRef = dataBaseRef2.child("teachers")
    self.teachersList.removeAll()
    teachersTableRef.observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let teachersNamesDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] ?? [:]
        for(key, _) in teachersNamesDictionary
        {
            if let teacherDict = teachersNamesDictionary[key] as? [String: Any]
            {
                if let teacher = Teacher(dictionary: teacherDict)
                {
                    //print(teacher.teacher_name)
                    self.teachersList.append(teacher.teacher_name)
                }
            }
        }
        let exists = self.teachersList.contains(teacherName)
        completion(exists)
    })
}
```

And call function as below

```
teacherExists(teacherName: newTeacherName) { (exists) in
    if exists {
        // show alert
    } else {
        // add new teacher to db
    }
}
```

Hope it help!

Comment: I am calling this method from an Alert OK button. But calling this function is giving error. I am not good at using closures.

Comment: awesome man....perfectly worked...this action is vey important for my app as I can't allow duplicate values in the database...you are a life saver...tons of thanks

Answer (score 0):

> getting error upon calling teacherExists function

```
let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler:
    {
        (action: UIAlertAction!) ->Void in
        let textfield = alert.textFields![0] as UITextField
        newTeacherName = textfield.text!.uppercased()
        if !(newTeacherName.isEmpty)
        {
            //checking if teacher already exists using function teacherExists
            let exists = self.teacherExists(teacherName: newTeacherName, completion:

            if exists == true //if duplicate teacher is found
            {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Duplicate Teacher", message: "Teacher \(newTeacherName) has been added earlier", preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            else
            {
                //add teacher to database here
                let dict = ["teacher_name" : newTeacherName]
                let newTeacher = Teacher(dictionary: dict)
                let tableRef = self.dataBaseRef.child("teachers") //getting reference of node with name teachers
                let recordRef = tableRef.childByAutoId() //creating a new record in teachers node
                recordRef.setValue(newTeacher!.toDictionary())//adding data to new record in teachers node
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: help me with calling teacherExists function using completion: